# Sort an array with the sort method in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have written this code but it isn't working . It's displaying the unsorted array as well as the button but when I click on the button nothing happens.
I am new to javascript. What I know so far is that we can call functions using the onclick method by javascript. We can write functions as we write in c or c++ . That's what I think I have done here but it isn't showing the sorted array .

```js
var myarray = [4, 6, 2, 1, 9, ];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myarray;

function sort(myarray) {
  var count = array.length - 1,
    swap,
    j,
    i;

  for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      if (array[i] > myarray[i + 1]) {
        swap = myarray[i + 1];
        myarray[i + 1] = myarray[i];
        myarray[i] = swap;
      }
    }
    document.write(myarray);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to sort the array.</p>
<button onclick="sort()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: @mmm its attached to button click.  Also @Nancy, you should check your console. there is an error `array is not defined`

Comment: Check you function, then check console, there are obvious errors in your code (hint: array vs myarray). And stop using document.write.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is, to decide if a parameter should be set or not. If not, then use `myarray` for all operations. If you decide to use a parameter, then use only the parameter variable.

```js
var myarray = [4, 6, 2, 1, 9, ];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myarray;

function sort() {                                        // no need for a parameter
    var count = myarray.length - 1,                      // change it to myarray
        swap,
        j, i;

    for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (myarray[i] > myarray[i + 1]) {           // access only myarray
                swap = myarray[i + 1];
                myarray[i + 1] = myarray[i];
                myarray[i] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myarray; // return the sorted array
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to sort the array.</p>
<button onclick="sort()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myarray = [4, 6, 2, 1, 9];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myarray;

function sort(myarray) {
  var count = myarray.length - 1,
    swap,
    j,
    i;

  for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      if (myarray[i] > myarray[i + 1]) {
        swap = myarray[i + 1];
        myarray[i + 1] = myarray[i];
        myarray[i] = swap;
      }
    }       
  }
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myarray;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to sort the array.</p>
<button onclick="sort(myarray)">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 problems with your code. The first is that you wrote `array` instead of `myarray` in 2 lines:

```
var count = array.length - 1,
```

and

```
if (array[i] > myarray[i + 1]) {
```

The second problem is that you didn't pass your array as argument, when calling the function, so:

```
<button onclick="sort()">Try it</button>
```

should be:

```
<button onclick="sort(myarray)">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you array definition has an extra `,` at the end.
Next, you have made use of `array` and not `myarray` in the if statement.

Once you sort, you need to have a statement:

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myarray;`

Comment: Its fine to use arrays with extra `,`. this does not gives any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a variable 'array' which is not defined or known to the function. Moreover on buttonclick you are not passing any parameter to sort function. That's the reason you're getting an error.

```
var myarray = [4, 6, 2, 1, 9, ];

function sort(myarray) {
  var count = myarray.length - 1,
    swap,
    j,
    i;

  for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      if (myarray[i] > myarray[i + 1]) {
        swap = myarray[i + 1];
        myarray[i + 1] = myarray[i];
        myarray[i] = swap;
      }
    }
    document.write(myarray);
  }
}

<p>Click the button to sort the array.</p>
<button onclick="sort(myarray)">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```